# Jquery Masonry checkerboarding

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

For some reason my jquery masonry treats col1 and col2 differently although they are the same in CSS (besides color and margin)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#container').masonry({
            columnWidth:800
        });

$('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.col1',
            columnWidth: 150
         });

        $('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.col2',
            columnWidth: 150
        });
});
```

Col2 sits to the right and is just below col1, just like a checkerboard.  Here is a link to JSfiddler with the code.  Can anyone spot why this results as such?
[JS Fiddler Code of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArgyleGost/VBacg/29/)
Thanks,
Argyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal when you have 3 columns and have only 1 brick in each column. What would you expect from a program that basically solve a difficult mathematical problem when you give it only one or two variables? It's a solution but maybe not the best? Try to add more bricks to each container and you can see how the algorithm solve your problem?

As requested I suggest you to read the masonry documentation and my answer again but if you only want to add the masonry algorithm to the main content you don't need it for each brick:

```
 $('#container').masonry({
        columnWidth:800
    });

    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.col1',
        columnWidth: 150
     });

    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.col2',
        columnWidth: 150
    });

     $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.col3',
        columnWidth: 150
    });
```

Just add it 1 time and change all your bricks have 1 selector for example:

```
   $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.main',
        columnWidth: 150
    });
```

Comment: What Im aiming for is just to have masonry in the main content and leave the header and left navbar masonry-free.  Adding more bricks to the main content ("container") does not solve this issue.  I guess I am not totally understanding as to what you are stating as a solution.

You can see by adding more bricks that it does not solve much
[VIEW CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/ArgyleGost/VBacg/37/)

Comment: I see.  Thanks so much.  The masonry documentation is brief and needs a better help page.  Maybe they can pay you as a contractor :)  Thanks for the help Chiyou